# Cannot run FastMember based console app

Tags: .net, fastmember

I'm just playing around with [FastMember](http://nuget.org/packages/FastMember) and have hit a problem.

Each time I start my console app I get the following exception:

> Could not load type 'FastMember.ObjectAccessor' from assembly
>   'FastMember, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

I installed FastMember via NuGet, and here is my code:

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p = new Person();

        var accessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(p);

        Console.WriteLine(accessor["GetHtml"]);
    }
}

public sealed class Person
{
    public string GetHtml()
    {
        return "";
    }
}
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here. Can I use FastMember like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not seeing your problem.  Would like to mention that the code as you have it does not work.

I did not get it working with functions, but your code looks like it could be a property, all the same...

```
using System;
using FastMember;

public class Program
{
   private static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      var p = new Person();

      var accessor = ObjectAccessor.Create(p);

      Console.WriteLine(accessor["Html"]);
   }
}

public sealed class Person
{
   public string Html
   {
      get
      {
         return "<a/>";
      }
   }
}
```

**EDIT** It's instructive to have a look at unit tests, as they show working examples.

Comment: Ahhh, FastMembers only picks up properties? If that's the case then it makes sense why my code does not work.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer/comment. Sorry I didn't upvote - I'm in the middle of moving house, which meant I quickly read your answer but then had to go on box moving duty! I've upvoted you now bud.

Comment: I recently moved as well, I hear ya.